# Algorithm to generate all letter combinations using recursion

Tags: java

I remember this having a specific name, and there were example codes on various websites - but I can't remember what it was actually called so can't find anything...

Basically, I want to generate all the possible letter combinations in a loop. The output would be something like this:

```
A
B
C
...
Z
AA
AB
AC
---
AZ
BA
BB
BC
```

etc...

Comment: permutations, I think the key word you're searching for is permutations.

Comment: @wheaties - These are really _not_ permutations. How can 'A', 'BA' and 'AZ' be permutations of one another?

Comment: @adamk Until you editted it, it read like he wanted permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (pseudocode):

```
function loop(prefix, max_length):
   for c in 'A' to 'Z':
      print prefix + c

   for c in 'A' to 'Z':
      if length(prefix) < max_length:
         loop( prefix + c, max_length)

 loop('', 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to port that to Java but I'm not sure what "for c in 'A' to 'Z'" should be?

Comment: @Matt: it means that `c` should range over the letters `A` through `Z`. In Java you can use a regular `for` loop for this.

Comment: So is this correct?
String[] chars = {"a", "b", "c"};
for (String c : chars) {

Comment: for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)

Answer (score 5):

Mathematically speaking, you are looking for the [cartesian power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_square_and_Cartesian_power) of the alphabet.

The recursion adamk provided is correct, but you can simplify it a little:

```
void printAllLetterSequences(String prefix, int length) {
    System.out.println(prefix);
    if (prefix.length() < length)
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
            printAllLetterSequences(prefix + c, length);
}
```

Comment: It's a nice, clean code, but the results are returned in a different order than in the question (and adamk's answer).  I cannot understand from the question whether or not the ordering of the results is important.